# Is there a way to update only certain elements in an EnvironmentObject

Tags: swift, swiftui

For example, I would like each list element to be independent of the other's data.

Such that, changing the name of one will not affect the other. But I also want the list to be updated if they are altered from another view.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var listView = People()
    let tempPerson = Person()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                self.listView.people.append(self.tempPerson)
            }){
                Text("Add person")
            }
            ListView().environmentObject(listView)
        }.onAppear{self.listView.people.append(self.tempPerson)}
    }
}

struct ListView : View {
    @EnvironmentObject var listView : People

    var body: some View{
        List(listView.people.indices, id: \.self) { index in
            TextField("StringProtocol", text: self.$listView.people[index].name)
        }
    }
}
```

```
class Person {
    var name = "abc"
}

class People : ObservableObject {
    @Published var people : [Person]

    init() {
        self.people = []
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Person` is a class. Which means if you create:

```
let tempPerson = Person()
```

then in every place inside your `ContentView` you'll refer to the same `Person` instance - and you'll append the same person in your button action:

```
Button(action: {
    self.listView.people.append(self.tempPerson)
}) {
    Text("Add person")
}
```

I recommend you change your `Person` to be a *struct* instead of a *class*:

```
struct Person {
    var name = "abc"
}
```

As structs are copied, every time you append a new item:

```
self.listView.people.append(self.tempPerson)
```

it will be a *copy* of the original `tempPerson` and you'll be able to change your items independently.

You can read more here: [Structures and Classes](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ClassesAndStructures.html)